# java.sql.BatchUpdateException: I/O Error: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Tags: java, sql-server, sockets

I connect to a MSSQL Server 2008 SP3 with jtds 1.3.1.I create 3 PreparedStatements in 3 seperate Threads an add Querys to them. When i execute the PreparedStatements i get this exception:

```
 java.sql.BatchUpdateException: I/O Error: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeBatch(JtdsStatement.java:1091)
    at de.mvn.gotdb_mvn.Main.main(Main.java:181)
```

please help me solve the Problem. This is my  code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException
{

    final Importer importer = new Importer();
    importer.openConnection();
    final Connection connection = importer.getCon();
    importer.createNewTables();

    StatementPreparer test_falldata = new StatementPreparer(connection.prepareStatement(q1)) {

        @Override
        public void doRun()
        {
            try
            {
                PreparedStatement falldata_stmt = getStmt();
                // |         
                String[] line = this.getLine();
                falldata_stmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(line[0].trim()));
                //FallNr
                falldata_stmt.setString(2, line[1]);
                //DRG
                falldata_stmt.setString(3, line[18]);
                //MDC
                falldata_stmt.setString(4, line[19]);
                //PCCL
                falldata_stmt.setString(5, line[20]);
                falldata_stmt.addBatch();

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };

    StatementPreparer test_diagnosen = new StatementPreparer(connection.prepareStatement(q2)) {

        @Override
        public void doRun()
        {
            try
            {
                PreparedStatement diagnosen_stmt = getStmt();

                String[] line = this.getLine();
                String[] diagnose_only = line[13].split("~");

                for (int i = 0; i < diagnose_only.length; i++)
                {
                    int index_of_roof = diagnose_only[i].indexOf("^");
                    //FallNr
                    diagnosen_stmt.setString(1, line[1]);
                    //Code 
                    diagnosen_stmt.setString(2, diagnose_only[i].substring(0, index_of_roof));
                    //Used int
                    diagnosen_stmt.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(diagnose_only[i].substring(index_of_roof + 1, index_of_roof + 2)));
                    //HDX/NDX int
                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        diagnosen_stmt.setInt(4, 1);
                    } else
                    {
                        diagnosen_stmt.setInt(4, 0);
                    }
                    diagnosen_stmt.addBatch();
                }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    };

    StatementPreparer test_proceduren = new StatementPreparer(connection.prepareStatement(q3)) {

        @Override
        public void doRun()
        {
            try
            {
                PreparedStatement proceduren_stmt = getStmt();

                String[] line = this.getLine();
                String[] procedure_only = line[14].split("~");

                for (String single_proce : procedure_only)
                {
                    if (!single_proce.isEmpty())
                    {
                        int index_of_amp = single_proce.indexOf("&");
                        //fallnr
                        proceduren_stmt.setString(1, line[1]);
                        //code
                        proceduren_stmt.setString(2, single_proce.substring(0, index_of_amp));

                        //lokalisation
                        if (single_proce.lastIndexOf("&") == index_of_amp + 1)
                        {
                            proceduren_stmt.setString(4, "");
                            //Datum
                            proceduren_stmt.setDate(3, getProcedureDate(single_proce, proce_no_lok));
                        } else
                        {
                            String lokalisation = single_proce.substring(index_of_amp + 1, single_proce.lastIndexOf("&"));
                            proceduren_stmt.setString(4, lokalisation);
                            //Datum
                            proceduren_stmt.setDate(3, getProcedureDate(single_proce, proce_with_lok));
                        }
                        //used
                        proceduren_stmt.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(single_proce.substring(single_proce.indexOf("^") + 1, single_proce.indexOf("^") + 2)));
                        proceduren_stmt.addBatch();

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    };

    PreparerListener listener = new PreparerListener();
    test_falldata.addListener(listener);
    test_diagnosen.addListener(listener);
    test_proceduren.addListener(listener);
    try
    {

        for (String nextline = importer.getNextLine(); nextline != null; nextline = importer.getNextLine())
        {
            test_falldata.setLine(nextline);
            test_diagnosen.setLine(nextline);
            test_proceduren.setLine(nextline);
            test_falldata.resumeThread();
            test_diagnosen.resumeThread();
            test_proceduren.resumeThread();
        }

        if(!connection.isClosed())
        {   
            test_falldata.getStmt().executeBatch();
            if(connection.isClosed())
            {
            System.out.print("CLOSED");
            System.exit(-10);
            }
            test_diagnosen.getStmt().executeBatch();// Exception 
            test_proceduren.getStmt().executeBatch();
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("Connection has Closed");
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The OpenConnection Method:

```
   public void openConnection(String p_propertys)
   {
     try{
      Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
     String url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://LB236/checkpointDB;loginTimeout=30;socketTimeout=1800";
     String user ="jadmin";
     String pw="jadmin123";
     con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pw);
     }catch(Exception e){e.printStacktrace();}
   }
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your code, but my first guess would be that you're only using one database connection, that is subsequently used by multiple threads. This seems to be backed up by the fact that you only call openConnection() once.

Comment: The Threads dont use the connection only the PreparedStatement